# Remove Woocommerce product from cart with ajax/fetch

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with removing products from the cart in Woocommerce and I think it has to do with `WC_Cart::remove_cart_item`. I only get these error messages:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/esport/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 3046ms]

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

The products are looped over from my latte (php) file and adding a `data-key` attribute to each `<li>` element.

```
{var $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart()}
<section class="sidebar-checkout">
        <div class="sidebar-checkout__header">
            <h3 n:ifcontent>Varukorg</h3>
            <button class="cart-checkout-close"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="w-8 mr-4 icon-close"><path class="secondary" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15.78 14.36a1 1 0 0 1-1.42 1.42l-2.82-2.83-2.83 2.83a1 1 0 1 1-1.42-1.42l2.83-2.82L7.3 8.7a1 1 0 0 1 1.42-1.42l2.83 2.83 2.82-2.83a1 1 0 0 1 1.42 1.42l-2.83 2.83 2.83 2.82z"></path></svg></button>
        </div>
        <ul class="sidebar-cart" n:if="$cart_items">
            <li n:foreach="$cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item" class="sidebar-cart__item" data-key="{$cart_item_key}">
                {var $product = $cart_item['data']}
                {var $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url($product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail')}
                {var $image_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, "_wp_attachment_image_alt", TRUE)}
                <img src="{$img_src}" alt="{$image_alt}" decoding="async" loading="lazy">
                <a href="{get_permalink($product->get_id())}">{$product->get_name()}</a>
                <button class="remove_from_cart_button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="w-8 mr-4 icon-trash"><path class="primary" d="M5 5h14l-.89 15.12a2 2 0 0 1-2 1.88H7.9a2 2 0 0 1-2-1.88L5 5zm5 5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v6a1 1 0 0 0 2 0v-6a1 1 0 0 0-1-1zm4 0a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v6a1 1 0 0 0 2 0v-6a1 1 0 0 0-1-1z"></path><path class="secondary" d="M8.59 4l1.7-1.7A1 1 0 0 1 11 2h2a1 1 0 0 1 .7.3L15.42 4H19a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H5a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h3.59z"></path></svg></button>
            </li>
            <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content"></div>
        </ul>
</section>
```

The key attributes are picked up by my javascript file and then sent by the fetch function and received by the `wp_ajax_` custom function.

```
const remove_from_cart_button = document.querySelectorAll('.remove_from_cart_button');
remove_from_cart_button.forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', async e => {
        const key = e.target.closest('.sidebar-cart__item').dataset.key;
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/esport/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: 'action=my_custom_action&cart_item_key=' + key
                }
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log('data', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
)})
```

And my final ajax function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback');

function my_custom_action_callback() {
    $cart_item_key = $_POST['cart_item_key'];
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $item) {
        if ($key == $cart_item_key) {
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($key);
            wp_send_json_success(array('message' => 'Cart item removed successfully'));
        }
    }
  
}
```

If I remove `WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($key);` It sends back the json message without problem.
I have tried using `woocommerce_remove_cart_item` directly in the `action` fetch but I also get an error there.

Comment: Then it must be something in the WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($key) call. Go to your server error logs and check which php error is behind that status 500.

Comment: My error log doesnt display any errors for this problem. The last log is from the 25:th, before I tried `WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($key)`.

Comment: Try replacing foreach loop with WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key)

Comment: @IvoJerkovic I tried that first and it just gives the same exact error

Comment: Well, then there are 2 things, maybe $cart_item_key isn't correct or WC() cart is null or something. Can you print_r both of them and see the result?

Comment: @IvoJerkovic Well in the inspector tool I see that WC()->cart holds the correct corresponding keys for each of the items in the cart. $cart_item_key is also correct and the same value as the item in WC()->cart. The only problem is that remove_cart_item is not working.

Answer (score 0):

add [`wp_die()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/) at the end of your function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback');

function my_custom_action_callback() {
    $cart_item_key = $_POST['cart_item_key'];
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $item) {
        if ($key == $cart_item_key) {
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($key);
            wp_send_json_success(array('message' => 'Cart item removed successfully'));
            wp_die();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does not make any difference for me sadly

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your function with this one:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback');

function my_custom_action_callback() {

    if( empty($_POST['cart_item_key']) ){
        wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Cart item key empty!'));
    }

    $cart_item_key = $_POST['cart_item_key'];

    try {
        if(WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key)){
            wp_send_json_success(array('message' => 'Cart item removed successfully'));
        }else{
            wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Something was wrong for key '.$cart_item_key));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        wp_send_json_error(array('message' => $e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

This code will check the cart key, check if the item was removed and catch any exceptions and return the error message.  This **is not a fix** to your problem but a way to figure out what's happening. It's very unusual to get the code 500 without any traces in the error log. This should at least prevent the 500 and print the error.  `remove_cart_item` is a very short and simple function that should not cause any problems but there are 2 hooks called inside and some other code could be causing this.

Comment: The if statement didnt give me any clarity since the `remove_cart_item` function still gave me the same error. However I looked at the function code (`public function remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key )` in `class-wc-cart.php` located in the woocommerce plugin. The error seems to come from `do_action( 'woocommerce_remove_cart_item', $cart_item_key, $this );`
Im not sure if I can do anything here? The variables thats passed into that function are correct.

Comment: To quickly check,you can comment out that line in the woocommerce file. If that fixes the problem then you uncomment it and try to find the code which is hooked into that hook. It could be some custom code or some plugin.

Comment: Hmm that seems like it worked, and I forgot that I've tried to hook another function to the `woocommerce_remove_cart_item` so now with that removed it works. I can remove items successfully! However do you know what `woocommerce_remove_cart_item` does? I only see that it's used with `do_action` and never `add_action` in the docs. Or is the only purpose to hook custom code to it?

Comment: do_action will run any actions that are added by add_action or add_filter. You have to uncomment this line as next woocommerce update will overwrite the change anyways. But now that we know where the error is, you can remove that other function you hooked. I guess you tried to remove an item from the cart inside the woocommerce_remove_cart_item hook but that triggered the same hook again causing the infinite loop. Getting code 500 without any error log is a good hint that some code is in the loop that never ends.